# How to select monitored instances on stackdriver

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

> You have 45 days left in your Stackdriver Premium

If we go premium, how do we choose which instances are to be monitored. Is that even possible? I don't want to pay 8$ per month for the instances that don't require monitoring.

All I have found is this [article](https://support.stackdriver.com/customer/portal/articles/1491785-collecting-data-from-specific-resources-only):

> To have the Stackdriver service ignore a specific instance, add a tag named "stackdriver_monitor" with a value of "false".

but this is for EC2 instances. I'm using GCE platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently for GCE you'd have to use a different project and a different Stackdriver account for resources that you do not want to pay for in the premium tier, as Stackdriver monitors every resource in a Google Cloud Platform project. We're working on more flexible solutions.
Thanks,
Amir.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's about time I publicly rant about my stackdriver experience so far.

First of all, the recent migration caused multiple issues that took several days to fix. I know you guys are very busy, but that takes me to my next point. Stackdriver is not ready to come out of beta.

Comment: The majority of our instances don't required monitoring. We have no choice but to stick with basic tier until this gets fixed. Without an ETA on a "more flexible solution", we might roll out our own monitoring solution. In this case there's no coming back to stackdriver.