# In Stackdriver, How can I edit number of resource?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

Recently, Google started charging for stackdriver service. Its 8 USD per resource, and I would like to opt for single service only. But in my selected project it have 4 resources, If I select single project, it takes all 4 resources, which I do not need. And it will charge me more.

Is their any configuration change, where i can alter to select required resource only?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think you can do this yet (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158771/how-to-select-monitored-instances-on-stackdriver?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, you cannot select which resources to monitor in your Stackdriver account. All resources created in the projects within your Stackdriver account are monitored.